# If you play an engine in Arena, how do you send it setoption commands?

Tags: engines

I really want to play two engines against each other, one with a tablebase path and one without, but I assume this is just a special case of the question in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install engine with tb path
   1.1. Load that engine
   1.2. Configure the engine and set the tb path
2. Install another engine without tb path

Now you can use those engines to play games.

Comment: Reinstalled and now English.chm works, so I should be OK. I thought Arena had no user manual.